# Drag Multiple Elements in KineticJS (Without Grouping)

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I currently have an app that creates groups, where each group contains one line object and one text object (displays length of line). I have it so that the group is draggable, however I am now implementing a multi-select option where the user can click on two groups at once.

Is it possible to have a drag on one of those lines to effect both lines? I would like to avoid creating a super-group that contains the two previous groups if at all possible.

The only way I can think of doing this currently is through the super group similar to as follows:

```
var super_group = new Kinetic.Group({
  draggable: true
});

// clicked_groups is an array storing all groups that have been clicked (multi-select)
for(var i = 0; i < clicked_groups.length; i++) {
  super_group.add(clicked_groups[i]);
}
```

Or something to that effect. Any method that would allow me to drag multiple elements at once without creating a new group would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can drag multiple selections without needing a super-group.

First, create an array that holds a reference to all selected groups.

Then if one of the selected groups is dragged you can manually move all groups in the selected groups array.  (Move them by the distance the mouse has moved since the last move event).

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/PZzXm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var selectedGroups=[];


    var nextIndex=1;
    var nextX=20;
    var nextY=20;

    newGroup("red");
    newGroup("green");
    newGroup("blue");

    function newGroup(color){
        addGroup(color,nextIndex,nextX,nextY);
        nextIndex++;
        nextX+=50;
    }

    function addGroup(color,index,contentX,contentY){
        var g=new Kinetic.Group({draggable:true});
        g.on("dblclick",function(){
            this.isSelected=!this.isSelected;
            g.selector.stroke((this.isSelected)?"red":null);
            selectedGroups.length=0;
            layer.find("Group").each(function(child){
                if(child.isSelected){ selectedGroups.push(child); }
            });
            layer.draw();
        });
        g.on("dragstart",function(){
            g.startPos=stage.getPointerPosition();
        })
        g.on("dragmove",function(){
            if(!this.isSelected){return;}
            var n=selectedGroups.length;
            var endPos=stage.getPointerPosition();
            var dx=endPos.x-this.startPos.x;
            var dy=endPos.y-this.startPos.y;
            this.startPos=endPos;
            while(--n>=0){
                var group=selectedGroups[n];
                group.x(group.x()+dx);
                group.y(group.y()+dy);
            }
        });
        layer.add(g);
        var selector=new Kinetic.Rect({
            x:contentX, y:contentY, width:50, height:50,
        });
        g.add(selector);
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x:contentX+25, y:contentY+25, radius:20,
            fill:color,
        });
        g.add(circle);
        var text=new Kinetic.Text({
            x:contentX+25-3, y:contentY+25-8, text:index, fill:"white",fontSize:14,
        });
        g.add(text);
        g.index=index;
        g.selector=selector;
        g.isSelected=false;
        layer.draw();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>DoubleClick to select a circle-group<br>Dragging selection will drag all selected groups</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you  help me out with a similar problem? I am stuck for weeks. I am not using `group` method, but i have different objects which i need to select.